# Where is the source code of llvm-otool (mac)?

Tags: macos, llvm, otool

macOS has llvm-otool in its CommandLineTools.

Is llvm-otool in llvm? I don't see it in the llvm source code at https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git.

Does anybody know where to find its source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source code for open source parts of Apple software is available at https://opensource.apple.com/. Specifically, `otool` sources should be here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/ and here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/llvmCore/ (according to its man page, `llvm-otool` is just a shim that calls LLVM's `objdump`).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to download the code via git (I need the revision history)?

Comment: There’s an unofficial mirror of some of those projects at https://github.com/opensource-apple. Otherwise I don’t think so, you’ll have to download and diff the versions you want yourself.

Comment: Where is man objdump(1)? I don't see it installed alone with CommandLineTools.

Comment: If you mean the sources for `llvm-objdump` man page, I don't see them anywhere on Apple's site, only upstream (mirrored at https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/docs/llvm-objdump.1).

Comment: I mean on my Mac machine with CommandLineTools installed. I don’t find the man page installed.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in an `llvm-otool` to upstream LLVM here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/1a3f88658a02be6be5224fca9d9123b79958f289

Documentation: https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-otool.html

It's not the one that ships with Xcode, but it behaves like it.